# Which file stores the docker image dependencies?

Tags: docker

In attempt to learn our company properitary tool like docker I am trying to find out differences.

While we are make a docker container  how and which file stores list of dependencies and it's versions ?

What docker command can be used to list dependencies and it's all versions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a file named "`Dockerfile`". It contains commands that executed when building the image. The dependencies should be listed in the file (or referred by the file, for example, Python's requirements.txt).

A docker command `docker history --no-trunc=true [imagename]` can also dump all the commands that used to create the image.

Comment: in Docker we can use yum and pip to build and install software and  does it provide a mechanisms to figure out the dependency tree across all of the tools in that container environment to build them in the correct order all the way down to something as low level as gcc ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz If you meant that the Docker will automatically figure out the dependencies, the answer is no. It actually doesn't care about the commands of each building step, but just save every step's result as an "image".